# Optimizing a LINQ reading from System.Diagnostics.EventLog

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a performance problem on certain computers with the following query:

```
System.Diagnostics.EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application");

var entries = log.Entries
    .Cast<System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry>()
    .Where(x => x.EntryType == System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeGenerated)
    .Take(cutoff)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.Index,
        x.TimeGenerated,
        x.EntryType,
        x.Source,
        x.InstanceId,
        x.Message
    }).ToList();
```

Apparently `ToList()` can be quite slow in certain queries, but with what should I replace it?

Comment: Why have to case `.Cast<System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntry>()` specifically. `log.Entries` is type of `EventLogEntryCollection`.

Comment: You do not need the .ToList() but I find it very useful when debugging. It is needed only when you are casting to list objects.  You are using var so it is not required.

Comment: It isn't probably the `ToList()` that is slow, simply the `ToList()` causes the previous part of the query to be executed. If you replace a `ToList()` with directly a `foreach` you'll have nearly the same performance.

Comment: @user1672994 But `EventLogEntryCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, only `IEnumerable`.

Comment: This is exactly the same problem as classic one with Linq-To-SQLish-Databases. If you do a 'LINQ query' that degenerates to Linq-To-Objects instead of running as "to-SQL", then you fetch whole DB, millions of rows, then filter it on the client. Here, you read whole LOG. Apply the same solution: filter it on the database. Too bad the LOG's api does not support LINQ, and you have to use LOG's api to do the filter-on-db part, and only then play with LINQ on the results.. => see **Evk**'s answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`log.Entries` collection works like this: it is aware about total number of events (`log.Entries.Count`) and when you access individual element - it makes a query to get that element.

That means when you enumerate over whole `Entries` collection - it will query for each individual element, so there will be `Count` queries. And structure of your LINQ query (for example, `OrderBy`) forces full enumeration of that collection. As you already know - it's very inefficient.

Much more efficient might be to query only log entries you need. For that you can use `EventLogQuery` class. Suppose you have simple class to hold event info details:

```
private class EventLogInfo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can convert your inefficient LINQ query like this:

```
// query Application log, only entries with Level = 2 (that's error)
var query = new EventLogQuery("Application", PathType.LogName, "*[System/Level=2]");
// reverse default sort, by default it sorts oldest first
// but we need newest first (OrderByDescending(x => x.TimeGenerated)
query.ReverseDirection = true;            
var events = new List<EventLogInfo>();
// analog of Take
int cutoff = 100;
using (var reader = new EventLogReader(query)) {
    while (true) {
        using (var next = reader.ReadEvent()) {
            if (next == null)
                // we are done, no more events
                break;
            events.Add(new EventLogInfo {
                Id = next.Id,
                Source = next.ProviderName,
                Timestamp = next.TimeCreated,
                Message = next.FormatDescription()
            });
            cutoff--;
            if (cutoff == 0)
                // we are done, took as much as we need
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

It will be 10-100 times faster. However, this API is more low-level and returns instances of `EventRecord` (and not `EventLogEntry`), so for some information there might be different ways to obtain it (compared to `EventLogEntry`).

If you decide that you absolutely must use `log.Entries` and `EventLogEntry`, then at least enumerate `Entries` backwards. That's because newest events are in the end (its sorted by timestamp ascending), and you need top X errors by timestamp descended.

```
EventLog log = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog("Application");
int cutoff = 100;
var events = new List<EventLogEntry>();
for (int i = log.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // note that line below might throw ArgumentException
    // if, for example, entries were deleted in the middle
    // of our loop. That's rare condition, but robust code should handle it
    var next = log.Entries[i];
    if (next.EntryType == EventLogEntryType.Error) {
        // add what you need here
        events.Add(next);
        // got as much as we need, break
        if (events.Count == cutoff)
            break;
    }
}
```

That is less efficient, but still should be 10 times faster than your current approach. Note that it's faster because `Entries` collection is not materialized in memory. Individual elements are queried when you access them, and when enumerating backwards in your specific case - there is high chance to query much less elements.

Comment: I'd wrongly assumed since it has a `Count` property, the elements of the collection would be materialized immediately. Is this behavior documented anywhere? The [documentation for the `Entries` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entries?view=netframework-4.7.1) only states _the Entries member is automatically populated with the event log's list of entries._

Comment: @ZevSpitz I'm not aware of any explicit, clear documentation of this. Best I can do is point to source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/EventLogEntryCollection.cs

Comment: Hi. The conversion to EventLogReader works fine, but I can't seem to get the source of the event into my log file correctly, as ProviderName only prints out "Application" and I need a more detailed description.

Comment: @JussiLähteenmäki I've made a small test and in my case `ProviderName` corresponds to `Source` in all cases I checked. It contains values like `Application Hang`, `Application Error` and so on, never saw just "Application". But anyway, try to break with debugger and see what properties that `next` contains, to see if it contains what you need in some other property.

Comment: An update: .ProviderName gives the necessary information. Thanks.